# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs' problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to install blacksmith engine 2d and following the installation steps I can't get this to work correctly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when running the npm start command, it appears.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
```

and then the following error

```
 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\source\\js\\Black-Template\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev- 
server.js'
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your start script is something like

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server"
```

Please try to change it to

```
"start": "webpack serve"
```

I had the same problem, this change worked out for me. (Taken from:
https://programmerah.com/cannot-find-module-webpack-cli-bin-config-yargs-14915/)

Comment: i can confirm , i've fixed the problem changing "webpack-dev-server" to "webpack serve"